# Cannot resolve MVC View Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using pre setup Maven project from openshift and when I`m running the app on Tomcat the answer is "HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp"
Here is the web.xml

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class Test {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC - Hello World");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

My IDEA Spring service shows that it is not able to resolve "hello" in "return "hello";"
and there is no error in log just shows "HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp" when i ask for http://localhost:9999/welcome;
Appreciate everyone`s answer

PS here is the source code if anyone is interested, thanks

Comment: please add the error or exception logs.

Comment: Well, there is no error in log just shows "HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp" when i ask for http://localhost:9999/welcome.
the server starts just fine

Comment: Provide context name in URL (http://localhost:9999/yourProjectName/welcome) and hit again.

Comment: Thank you, already tried, does not help. Added source from github

Comment: BTW http://localhost:9999/restauranter/welcome shows HTTP Status 404 only without /WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp. which means controller works.... probably

Comment: can you post your dispatcher-servlet file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view resolver you are pointing to /WEB-INF/views instead use
    value="/WEB-INF/pages/"
Then hello.jsp should shows up.